# Grey out all unused vote buttons on old elections

Tags: feature-request, design, voting, user-interface, election

I'm hoping this is a "quick fix", but it's far from a priority. A small change might help a lot here.

I got some egg on my face yesterday when I [thought there was a bug with old election pages showing vote buttons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399219/old-elections-are-offering-vote-buttons). A new user thought the same thing and had asked in chat. It turns out that's by design

> Look at the candidates you voted for. The '1st', '2nd' and '3rd' choice buttons look different there; here are the buttons on the candidate I voted for as second choice:

Unless I get shown a candidate I did vote for, my screen looks like this

[image: Old election but the buttons look usable]

While voted candidates show like this (note 1st and 3rd are greyed out)

[image: Voted for this candidate]

I would like to see all the buttons, save ones I used to vote for, shown as greyed out. It would make it visually obvious that one cannot cast a new vote.

Comment: That’s still not *consistent*. When voting is open you can select any other candidate and move your 1st, 2nd or 3rd vote to them, which is why the buttons are not dimmed then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I beg to differ. If you vote for a question the up arrow is highlighted. If the same would be for elections we would dim all buttons by default and only highlight those selected.

Comment: @Luuklag that makes no sense. We don’t dim the downvote arrow when you upvoted a post either. The vote widget is different in that it offers multiple choices across multiple posts, but it *does* show what you picked, just like the highlighted up arrow sticks around when you upvoted something.

Comment: According to Yaakov [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361979/moderator-elections-functionality-voting-ui-commenting-and-flagging/362101#comment1207906_362101) this will be fixed with the new election system.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be even better to actually gray them out. Not lighten them out.

I quickly mocked up an example by altering the CSS. I added the last two lines, which fixes things for the candidates you did vote for.

```
.election-page .election-candidates .candidate-vote-button.not-selected-choice {
    opacity: .6;
    background-color: gray;
    border-color: gray;
```

[image]

This, however, won't work for candidates you didn't vote for, as they don't have any special CSS. For that, I think it would be best if we lose the vote buttons for finished elections completely, as the side of the page shows who we voted for:

[image]

Comment: No, losing the buttons changes the UI. Just like you can’t vote on your own post, you can’t vote on the candidates once the election is closed. But the buttons _remain_.