# Election buttons aren't styled anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election

Election buttons, e.g. in [this current election](https://music.stackexchange.com/election) seem to lack styling:

[image]

They used to be blue, like this screenshot (thanks [@Machavity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350639/295232)):

[image]

Comment: [You sure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2pcm.png) this is fixed, Aaron?

Comment: @Aaron there is now a difference between a candidate you've elected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKe7J.png (the chosen option is dark blue) and a candidate which you're about to elect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFGFd.png (I'm hovering over the 2nd button there).