# Voting buttons lose their style after voting for any candidate in election page

Tags: bug, design, election

In the [current election voting page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election), after voting for any of the choices, the voting buttons lose their style for the remaining candidates.

Initially the voting buttons look like below:

> [image: Three fully-styled buttons, with "1st choice" a darker shade of blue than "2nd choice" or "3rd choice", to show that "1st choice" was selected. All buttons have white text.]

After voting for any one of the candidates, for the remaining candidates, voting choices look like below:

> [image: Three buttons without background colors, with blue text. A mouse is shown hovering over each in turn, and the hovered buttons have a lighter shade of blue background.]

Comment: I noticed it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356118/election-buttons-arent-styled-anymore#comment1190982_356118) but no response. Good idea to post a new [tag:bug].

Comment: @Glorfindel I saw your post already, but it contains the status-completed tag, so I posted new, but missed your comments.

Comment: We probably won't fix this as is. We have an all-new vote indicating workflow rolling out soon so fixing this doesn't make a ton of sense, particularly when it's not persistent. Refreshing the page fixes the issue until you select another person.

Comment: The voting UI has been revamped, so this bug is no longer reproducible (cf. [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361979/moderator-elections-functionality-voting-ui-commenting-and-flagging)).